# iOS: get response from PHP

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift

I POST and GET data to/from my MySQL database with PHP. I want to get a response string.

For example:

A user wants to login in the app. Before storing the data and proceed I'll have to check if this username/password pair exists in my database.

```
@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://example.com/checklogin.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "username=\(username.text!)&password=\(password.text!)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
```

This will POST username and password to this checklogin.php file:

```
    <?php
    $root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
    include "$root/config.php";

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
    $statement->execute(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));

    $row = $statement->rowCount();

    if ($row == 1) {
/*      Send "true" to Xcode! */
    }
    else {
/*      Send "false" to Xcode! */
    }
```

This will check if the username/password pair exists.

I want to get a "true" or "false" response in iOS. If it's true user gets signed in. If it's "false" user gets an alert to check the login data.

What is the common way to send/get and handle responses like this? What is the common way achieve this?

Comment: You probably want to properly escape your password in the request as well as passwords are very likely to contain characters like `%` which can mess that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not return the data to your app directly but there are several ways to send the data to app : The simple way is :

Use this on PHP to echo true or false and then

```
if ($row == 1) {
 echo "true";
}
else {
  echo "false";
}
```

Add this to get Response in your swift app and check if It's true or false with an if statement:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
        print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
        print("response = \(response)")
    }

    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
}
task.resume()
```

NOTE: Be aware that It's not a good way but the simple way as you said it's just an example...

If you want to get more data from the server use JSON

Comment: What do I have to use, `response` or `responseString`?

Comment: Use responseString as it's encoding is correct , and try to check both of them to Improve your programming experience and coding...@David

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. It's working now. I had a very similar solution before, but your solution did the trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your welcome and read my edit note on the end of the answer, About JSON.

Comment: Okay, thank you. P.S. I know it's of topic, but what is `task.resume()`? Should I do my if/else above or below `task.resume()`?

Comment: When you create a task you use task.resume() And it means the task is finished.

Comment: I want to show an alert if "false" and store the data if true. Where do I put this statement? I don't really unterstand what `task.resume()` means.

Comment: Put it after that.

Comment: Okay, but I get `Use of unresolved identifier 'responseString'`. What can I do? Should I store the value of `responseString` in a `var` or `let`
? I tried it, but also doesn't work.